# Extract IE browsing history of the logged in user

Tags: c#, windows, internet-explorer, service, desktop-application

**Objective to achieve** : Extract IE browsing history of the logged in user. IE 11. 
 **Solution** : I am following <“http://theagussantoso.blogspot.com/2008/11/get-temporary-internet-explorer-files.html”>? link for the prospective solution. This is all working fine in my *Dev environment* (in VS 2017). I am getting all the browser history from “C:\Users[User Name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache”. 
  **Problem** :
The solution has to run as a “Service” on Windows. When the application runs as a Service on the system, it runs under “NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM” (found it through “WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name”) , therefore, the program flow is not able to find “C:\Users[User Name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache” location to read the IE history.
I have tried following solution as suggested by some links but none of them worked for me: 
 
Trial 1:

```
        IntPtr accessToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        WindowsIdentity identity =  new WindowsIdentity(accessToken); 
        LOG.Debug("Identity Name: " + identity.Name);
        WindowsImpersonationContext context = identity.Impersonate();
```

Getting error : token cannot be zero

Trial 2:  I was just trying to impersonate the user in my Dev, but it did not yield any results at all without throwing any error:

```
WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(); 
        LOG.Debug("Identity Name: " + identity.Name);
        WindowsImpersonationContext context = identity.Impersonate();

        //... my code here
        context.Undo();
```

I do not know how can I force my code to run under current logged in user so that the cache code will run to get data from “C:\Users[User Name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache”. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the ultimate aim of this? You would only ever get the data for IE11 (there is no *onwards*, IE11 is the last ever)  Perhaps a logging proxy server would be better (and would not be sensitive to history deletes/in-private).

Comment: Thanks for pointing there is no IE 11 onwards...

Comment: @AlexK , the ultimate goal is to have a list of websites which user has browsed in last 24 hrs. This job is going to run every day at certain time. Having a separate logging proxy server is not possible in my environment due to some constraints. I have to do some magic within the code OR a different mechanism to read entries under "C:\Users[User Name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache" directory.

Comment: Have you tried `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User`?

Comment: The API is IUrlHistoryStg2 but it is not supported in a service. you gotta call it in the user's session.

Comment: It seems, I am trying to achieve something impossible here because I just found a note from MS that **WinINet does not support server or service ** implementations.  Ref: [link]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384026(v=vs.85).aspx.  Now, I need to start from the scratch on how to read data from IE when the code is running as Service.